# How to change value inside textfield HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, textfield

How can I change the value inside my Revenue textfield by subtracting the Cost of Good value from the Sales Price value? I have attached an image of what it looks like currently, but I want to change whats displayed inside my Revenue field after I edit the previous 2 text fields. I have also attached my code.

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZrW.png)

[image]

```html
<div class="product-section">
  <h3>
    <b>{{ product.productLabel }}</b>
  </h3>
  <label for="sales-price">Sales Price: </label>
  <br>
  <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="product.salesPrice"
    name="sales-label"
    placeholder="Enter Sales Price"
  />
  <p></p>
  <label for="cogs">Cost of Good: </label>
  <br>
  <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="product.cogs"
    name="cogs-label"
    placeholder="Enter Cogs"
  />
  <p></p>
  <label for="rev">Revenue: </label>
  <br>
  <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="product.rev"
    name="rev-label"
    readonly
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Take the quotes away from `getRev()` so that it is invoked instead of just set as the string value of the text input.

Comment: Hey actually I don't think I can access the getRev() function as it is in a different named ts file. Also that line of code isn't valid as its just completely white. Is there a way to just subtract the cogs value from my sales value?

Answer (score 0):

Add `(keyup)="getRev()"` to your Sales Price and Cost of Goods inputs.

```
<div class="product-section">
    <h3>
        <b>{{ product.productLabel }}</b>
    </h3>
    <label for="sales-price">Sales Price: </label>
    <br>
    <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="product.salesPrice"
    (keyup)="getRev()"
    name="sales-label"
    placeholder="Enter Sales Price"
  />
    <p></p>
    <label for="cogs">Cost of Good: </label>
    <br>
    <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="product.cogs"
    (keyup)="getRev()"
    name="cogs-label"
    placeholder="Enter Cogs"
  />
    <p></p>
    <label for="rev">Revenue: </label>
    <br>
    <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="product.rev"
    name="rev-label"
    readonly
  />
</div>
```

Then add a function to your component's typescript file to handle the revenue calculation.

```
  getRev() {
    this.product.rev = this.product.cogs - this.product.salesPrice;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the body of getRev()? And, take the quotes away from getRev() so that it calls the function instead of sets the value as the literal string 'getRev()'

**Edit:**

*Is there a way to just subtract the cogs value from my sales value?*

Yes, you could use an onchange handler. Here is an example, assuming you set the ID of the three elements as 'cogs', 'sales', and 'revs':

```
const cogs = document.getElementById('cogs');
const sales = document.getElementById('sales');
const revs = document.getElementById('revs');

cogs.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
   const salesNumber = Number(sales.value);
   const cogsNumber = Number(cogs.value);
   const difference = salesNumber - cogsNumber;

   revs.value = difference;
  });
```

Comment: public getRev(): string {
      const revNum: number = Number(this.salesPrice) - Number(this.cogs);
      return revNum.toString();
  }